# kubernetes dial tcp i/o timeout error in version 1.7.0. Also kubeadm join command fails

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes, so some of my questions may be basic.

**NOTE: REMOVED http::// and https::// URL references in commands and output below, since there is a limit to number of URLs in a question.**

**My setup:** 
1 Physical host machine(running Ubuntu 16.04), with bridge networking enabled.

2 Ubuntu 16.04 VMs(Virtual Machines), VM1 is Master Node. VM2 is Slave Node.

I have a router, so behind the router both VMs get local IP address(ie not public IP address). 
Since I am on corporate network, I also have proxy settings. 
I have browser, apt, curl and wget applications working fine. Able to ping between VM1 and VM2.

**Kubernetes Version**: 1.7.0 on both Master Node(Virtual Machine-VM1) and Slave Node(Virtual Machine-VM2)

**My Steps:**
1. On both Master and Slave Nodes, installed the required kubernetes(kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni) packages and docker(docker.io) packages.

**On the Master Node:**
1. On the Master Node, when I run kubeadmin init, I was getting the following tcp timeout error:

sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.104 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 –skip-preflight- -checks

[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters. 
unable to get URL "storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable-1.7.txt": Get storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable-1.7.txt: dial tcp 172.217.3.208:443: i/o timeout

2. So tried specifying the kubernetes version, since I read that this prevents fetch from external website, and with that kubeadmin init was successful.

sudo kubeadm init --kubernetes-version v1.7.0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.104 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --skip-preflight-checks

[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters. 
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.7.0

[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]

[preflight] Skipping pre-flight checks

[certificates] Using the existing CA certificate and key.

[certificates] Using the existing API Server certificate and key.

[certificates] Using the existing API Server kubelet client certificate and key.

[certificates] Using the existing service account token signing key.

[certificates] Using the existing front-proxy CA certificate and key.

[certificates] Using the existing front-proxy client certificate and key.

[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"

[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date KubeConfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"

[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date KubeConfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"

[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date KubeConfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"

[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date KubeConfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"

[apiclient] Created API client, waiting for the control plane to become ready

[apiclient] All control plane components are healthy after 14.009367 seconds

[token] Using token: ec4877.23c06ac2adf9d66c 
[apiconfig] Created RBAC rules

[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy

[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-dns

Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!

To start using your cluster, you need to run (as a regular user):

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube

sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster. 
Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at: 
  kubernetes.io/docs/admin/addons/

You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node 
as root:

kubeadm join --token ec4877.23c06ac2adf9d66c 192.168.1.104:6443

3. Ran the below commands and they went through fine.
   mkdir -p $HOME/.kube 
   sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config 
   sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
4. Tried to deploy a pod network to the cluster, but fails with the same tcp timeout error:

kubectl apply -f 
docs.projectcalico.org/v2.3/ getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.6/calico.yaml

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 151.101.0.133:80: i/o timeout

5. Downloaded the calico.yaml file using browser, and ran the command, it was successful.

skris14@skris14-ubuntu16:~/Downloads$ sudo kubectl apply -f ~/Downloads/calico.yaml

configmap "calico-config" created

daemonset "calico-etcd" created

service "calico-etcd" created

daemonset "calico-node" created

deployment "calico-policy-controller" created

clusterrolebinding "calico-cni-plugin" created

clusterrole "calico-cni-plugin" created

serviceaccount "calico-cni-plugin" created

clusterrolebinding "calico-policy-controller" created

clusterrole "calico-policy-controller" created

serviceaccount "calico-policy-controller" created

**On the Slave Node:**

Note: I am able to do a basic ping test, and ssh, scp commands between the master node running in VM1 and slave node running in VM2 works fine.

1. Ran the join command, and it fails trying to get cluster info.

Output of join command in slave node:
skris14@sudha-ubuntu-16:~$ sudo kubeadm join --token ec4877.23c06ac2adf9d66c 192.168.1.104:6443

[sudo] password for skris14:

[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.

[preflight] Running pre-flight checks

[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "192.168.1.104:6443"

[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "192.168.1.104:6443"

[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get 192.168.1.104:6443/: EOF]
^C

**Output of Status Commands On the Master Node:**

skris14@skris14-ubuntu16:~/Downloads$ 
kubectl get nodes

NAME                      STATUS    AGE       VERSION
skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1   Ready     5d        v1.7.0

skris14@skris14-ubuntu16:~/Downloads$ kubectl cluster-info

Kubernetes master is running at 192.168.1.104:6443

KubeDNS is running at 192.168.1.104:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

skris14@skris14-ubuntu16:~/Downloads$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -o wide

NAME                                              READY     STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE

calico-etcd-2lt0c                                 1/1       Running    0          14m       192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

calico-node-pp1p9                                 2/2       Running    0          14m       192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

calico-policy-controller-1727037546-m6wqt         1/1       Running    0          14m       192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

etcd-skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1                      1/1       Running    1          5d        192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

kube-apiserver-skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1            1/1       Running    0          3m        192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

kube-controller-manager-skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1   1/1       Running    0          4m        192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

kube-dns-2425271678-b05v8                         0/3       Pending    0          4m

kube-dns-2425271678-ljsv1                         0/3       OutOfcpu   0          5d                  skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

kube-proxy-40zrc                                  1/1       Running    1          5d        192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

kube-scheduler-skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1            1/1       Running    5 5d 192.168.1.104   skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1

**Output of ifconfig on Master Node(Virtual Machine1):**

skris14@skris14-ubuntu16:~/

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:7f:ee:8e:b7  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:be:36:42:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c60c:647d:1d9d:aca1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:184500 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:458827 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:242793144 (242.7 MB)  TX bytes:9162254 (9.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:848277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:848277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:211936528 (211.9 MB)  TX bytes:211936528 (211.9 MB)

tunl0     Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.112.192  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

**Output of ifconfig on Slave Node(Virtual Machine2):**

skris14@sudha-ubuntu-16:~$ ifconfig 
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:69:5e:2d:22  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:be:36:42:b6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cadb:b714:c679:955/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:183622 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:98350159 (98.3 MB)  TX bytes:3431313 (3.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:130985 (130.9 KB)  TX bytes:130985 (130.9 KB)

Answer (score 0):

> discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get
>   192.168.1.104:6443/: EOF]

your error message shows slave not able to connect to master api server. check these items.

1. make sure api server running on port 6443
2. check the routes on both servers.
3. check the firewall rules on your hosts and router.

Comment: I tried all 3 suggestions, but issue still remains, unable to join to master node from slave. 1. I made sure that api server is running on port 6443, by running netstat command. And also checked through kubectl get pods command. Also ran nmap command and verified that port 6443 is open.2. Able to do traceroute from both nodes(master and slave) without any problem, as well as telent, ssh applications. 3. I have disabled the firewall on the host, both nodes as well as on the router.

Comment: ok, network connection is good, but your dns pod is not running we need to fix this. see you can restart the master node and check all pods in running  status. then run join command. "kube-dns-2425271678-b05v8 0/3 Pending 0 4m

kube-dns-2425271678-ljsv1 0/3 OutOfcpu 0 5d skris14-ubuntu16.04-vm1"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I deleted the master node as per kubernetes webpage for kubeadm, and restarted using kubeadm init. That didnt make a difference. But I came across this link(https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38806), that said, kube-DNS runs out of CPU resources, when guest Virtual Machine, is using just 1 CPU. So, I changed my qemu command line when launching both my VMs. Now I have kube-dns working fine, status is Running. But still when issuing kubeadm join command from slave node, it fails with the same error as before.

Comment: when you run kubeadm join, can you check you /var/log/syslog file on master node see any message logged there.

Comment: On the master node, didnt find anything when executing join command on the slave node. But just noticed this one debug, constantly being output on the master node:
Jul 10 06:37:26 skris14-ubuntu16 kubelet[2341]: W0710 06:37:26.912195    2341 helpers.go:771] eviction manager: no observation found for eviction signal allocatableNodeFs.available

Comment: On the slave node checked the /var/log/syslog file:Kubelet process gets started and stopped repeatedly, it keeps failing due to absence of kubelet.conf.
Jul 10 06:32:19 sudha-ubuntu-16 kubelet[9534]: error: failed to run Kubelet: invalid kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf: no such file or directory
Jul 10 06:32:19 sudha-ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 10 06:32:19 sudha-ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.

Comment: on the salve when you run kubeadm join command, it will create  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf file. did you kubernetes before on this slave node. on the slave try this. run kubeadm reset, then try to run the kubeadm join command.

Comment: I ran kubeadm reset on the slave node. Also manually had to delete the directory /etc/kubernetes on the slave node. And tried a fresh run of commands on the master node and slave node. Still getting the same error with join command.

Comment: running out of idea now, Its very simple process to setup the cluster. on the slave can you check docker process is in running status. Do you use proxy in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you get time out because join token expired, is no longer valid or does not exist on master node. If that is the case then you will not be able to join the cluster. What you have to do is to create new token on master node and use it in your `kubeadm join` command. More details in this
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193497/kubeadm-join-command-gets-timed-out-every-time-in-ubuntu-16-04/59790668#59790668).